# Open synced tabs in the new Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sync, mobile-phone, browser-tabs

Google Chrome updated a few days ago, and since then, I can't seem to access my synced tabs. How do I access my synced tabs in the new Google Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hVM63Pd6Lt8). They moved it to "History -> Show Full History". I guess it isn't used very often.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, it only shows one tab for me.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's probably a syncing issue instead.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a "History -> Show Full History".....

Comment: I'm using Chrome 42 (latest version) on Mac and I still see the option.

Comment: It’s still there, just tried it, Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (x86_64), Mac OS X.

Comment: Currently, the path is "History -> History (Ctrl+H) -> Tabs from other devices"